# Java Arrays increasing

Tags: java, arrays

I need help with one of my methods that lengthen an array. So if the array is ABC i want the void method to make it AABBCC. Here is my code so far:

```
public void lengthen(){ 
    double[]t = new double[samples.length];

    for(int i = 0;i<samples.length;i++){
        t[i] = samples[i];
    }
    samples = new double[t.length*2];
    for(int i = 0; i < samples.length;i++){
        samples[(2*i)] = t[i];
        samples[(2*i)+1] = t[i];
    } 
}
```

Comment: So? Did you test it to see if it works?

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: yes i keep getting out of bounds exception

Comment: @user3284325 as @Jake said, your second for loop goes from 0 to 1 less than the length of `samples`, which is clearly wrong. That's what's giving you the out of bounds exception.

Answer (score 0):

You want the second array to only increment to a maximum of `i/2` as you are filling two array elements in the loop body.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your loop iterates over the indexes of the *doubly-sized* array and uses that to index the *singly-sized* array, hence you out-of-bounds exception.

It can be done quite simply with something like:

```
public void lengthen() {
    // Create new array, twice as many elements.

    double [] t = new double[samples.length * 2];

    // Transfers the elements, n -> 2n, 2n+1, n ranging from 0 to N-1 inclusive.

    for (int i = 0; i < samples.length; i++) {
        t[i*2]   = samples[i]; // 0->0, 1->2, 2->4, ..., (N-1)->(2N-2).
        t[i*2+1] = samples[i]; // 0->1, 1->3, 2->5, ..., (N-1)->(2N-1).
    }

    // Load into member variable.

    samples = t;
}
```